# function to print from from a Json each item using a for loop golang

Tags: json, go

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type Response struct {
    Status  string `json:"status"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
    Result  []struct {
        BlockNumber       string `json:"blockNumber"`
        TimeStamp         string `json:"timeStamp"`
        Hash              string `json:"hash"`
        Nonce             string `json:"nonce"`
        BlockHash         string `json:"blockHash"`
        TransactionIndex  string `json:"transactionIndex"`
        From              string `json:"from"`
        To                string `json:"to"`
        Value             string `json:"value"`
        Gas               string `json:"gas"`
        GasPrice          string `json:"gasPrice"`
        IsError           string `json:"isError"`
        TxreceiptStatus   string `json:"txreceipt_status"`
        Input             string `json:"input"`
        ContractAddress   string `json:"contractAddress"`
        CumulativeGasUsed string `json:"cumulativeGasUsed"`
        GasUsed           string `json:"gasUsed"`
        Confirmations     string `json:"confirmations"`
    } `json:"result"`
}

func getapi(wallet string) ([]byte, error) {
    res, err := http.Get("https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=" + wallet + "&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=5Q4SS1XHV95SIPSCKK1FKCPGJSMRM2EI1K")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    return ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
}

func j_unm(body []byte) Response {
    var r Response
    err := json.Unmarshal(body, &r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error unmarshalling json data:", err)
    }
    return r
}

func printitem(r Response, jitem string) []string {
    item := []string{}
    for _, p := range r.Result {
        item = append(item, jitem+":"+p.jitem)
    }
    return item
}
```

```
package main


import "fmt"

func main() {
    gettrx, _ := getapi("0xf287E9f40f96C0cbAEAdD29Cf22E6CF5cC66030b")
    fmt.Println(printitem(j_unm(gettrx), "BlockNumber"))
}
```

I want to pass as `jitem` as variable. I got the following error.

`jitem is define as string, could be BlockNumber or TimeStamp`

`p.jitem undefined (type struct{BlockNumber string "json:\"blockNumber\""; TimeStamp string "json:\"timeStamp\""; Hash string "json:\"hash\""; Nonce string "json:\"nonce\""; BlockHash string "json:\"blockHash\""; TransactionIndex string "json:\"transactionIndex\""; From string "json:\"from\""; To string "json:\"to\""; Value string "json:\"value\""; Gas string "json:\"gas\""; GasPrice string "json:\"gasPrice\""; IsError string "json:\"isError\""; TxreceiptStatus string "json:\"txreceipt_status\""; Input string "json:\"input\""; ContractAddress string "json:\"contractAddress\""; CumulativeGasUsed string "json:\"cumulativeGasUsed\""; GasUsed string "json:\"gasUsed\""; Confirmations string "json:\"confirmations\""} has no field or method jitem)compilerMissingFieldOrMethod`

Comment: it is saying `p` which is an iterator in `r.Result` does not have `jitem` as a field. What is shown in above error message is the structure of `p`.

Comment: You should provide complete type definition and what your string parameter format is so that we can understand your code.

Comment: i add the completed code, if you change p.jitem for p.BlockNumber it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you want this?

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type Response struct {
    Status  string              `json:"status"`
    Message string              `json:"message"`
    Result  []map[string]string `json:"result"`
}

func getapi(wallet string) ([]byte, error) {
    res, err := http.Get("https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=" + wallet + "&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=5Q4SS1XHV95SIPSCKK1FKCPGJSMRM2EI1K")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    return ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
}

func j_unm(body []byte) Response {
    var r Response
    err := json.Unmarshal(body, &r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error unmarshalling json data:", err)
    }
    return r
}

func printitem(r Response, jitem string) []string {
    item := []string{}
    for _, p := range r.Result {
        item = append(item, jitem+":"+p[jitem])
    }
    return item
}

func main() {
    gettrx, _ := getapi("0xf287E9f40f96C0cbAEAdD29Cf22E6CF5cC66030b")
    fmt.Println(printitem(j_unm(gettrx), "blockNumber"))
}
```

Comment: For sure p.jitem is not a string, I want to add a variable like p.(variable)

Comment: all right, did you solve your problem?

Comment: no, that is the porblem is not a string

Comment: Thanks so much, is better in this case use map, I dint see it in that way.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

is `p.jitem` is string? if is this type is convertible to string,then use `string(p.jitem)`

```
func printitem(r Response, jItem string) []string {
//item := []string{}
items:= make([]string,0)
for _, p := range r.Result {
    items = append(items, jItem+":"+ string(p.jItem))
}
return items
```